# The Cauchy Product : Calculate the coefficients, $c_n$, in the product.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-product

I found this definition to be different from other ones and the answer makes me feel weird.

If $$A_{N}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}a_{n}x^n$$ and $$B_{N}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}b_{n}x^n,$$ calculate the coefficients $$c_n$$ in the product $$A_{N}(x)\cdot B_{N}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}c_{n}x^n+\sum_{n=N+1}^{n=2N}d_{n}x^n.$$
The answer was $$c_n=a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_ib_{n-i}+...+a_nb_0.$$
This answer got me pretty lost in thoughts so can someone explain it how did it managed to be this?

Comment: Try writing it out for, say, $N=4$. You should see the pattern. Note that for each term $a_i b_j$, we have $i+j=n$, which means that it corresponds to the term $x^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obtained by distributivity, knowing that, using a more compact notation for the product of polynomials,

$$\biggl(\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{n=0}^N b_nx^n\biggr)= \sum_{n=0}^{2N} \biggl(\sum_{\,i+j=n}a_ib_j\biggr)x^n.$$
If $\:0\le n\le N$, for each $i$ such that  $0\le  i\le n$, $\:j=n-i$ also satisfies the condition $0\le j\le n$, whence the formula
$$c_n=\sum_{i=0}^na_ib_{n-i}\qquad\text{if}\quad 0\le n\le N.$$

Comment: Is this any way to do with the inverse problem? i.e.,  we know $c_n$ and relation between $c_n$ and $a_n, $b_n$, can we find $a_n$ and $b_n$?